# Oldest archive files not removed when using SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP when rolling over and there are multiple archive files for the oldest interval

Tags: logback

There seems to be a problem with how the maxHistory argument is implemented.
I roll over multiple times withing the time interval (every minute
here), creating the following files : (maxHistory = 3)

- trace.log (active file)
- trace-2013-03-13-16.14.0.log.zip
- trace-2013-03-13-16.13.0.log.zip
- trace-2013-03-13-16.12.2.log.zip
- trace-2013-03-13-16.12.1.log.zip
- trace-2013-03-13-16.12.0.log.zip

The nex time rollover occurs, the 16.13.0.log.zip file is removed, and
not the oldest ones (12.{0,1,2} as I would have expected. Is this
intended behaviour ?

```
 public static Logger createTimeAndSizeRollingLogger(String fileBase, String maxSize, int maxHistory, String resolutionPattern) {
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    appender.setContext(loggerContext);
    appender.setFile(fileBase + ".log");

    TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> timePolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
    timePolicy.setFileNamePattern(fileBase + "_%d{" + resolutionPattern + "}-%i.log.zip");
    timePolicy.setContext(loggerContext);
    timePolicy.setMaxHistory(maxHistory);
    timePolicy.setParent(appender);
    appender.setRollingPolicy(timePolicy);

    SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP<ILoggingEvent> rollingPolicy = new SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP<ILoggingEvent>();
    rollingPolicy.setMaxFileSize(maxSize);
    rollingPolicy.setTimeBasedRollingPolicy(timePolicy);
    rollingPolicy.setContext(loggerContext);

    timePolicy.setTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy(rollingPolicy);
    timePolicy.start();
    rollingPolicy.start();
    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
    encoder.setPattern("%msg%n");
    encoder.start();

    appender.setEncoder(encoder);
    appender.start();

    Logger logger = loggerContext.getLogger(fileBase);
    logger.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
    logger.addAppender(appender);
    StatusPrinter.print(loggerContext);
    return logger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

THis seems to be fixed in the lastest 1.1.0 SNAPSHOT
http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-162

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. MaxHistory will not work with SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP.
You can check it [here](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-747?jql=text%20~%20%22SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP%22)

You will find many people saying that it is solved, but it is not. If you want to fix it you can edit SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP.java which is located inside logback-core. You can see it [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/993b3ccd176b85f217473b897670d78090d4c7dc/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP.java) . Inside isTriggeringEvent is the place to add the code in my opinion.